# Decreasing or ascending list

Tags: python, list

How do I go through a list like this:
`list = [0, 1, 8 , 10, 14, 16]`

Observing if the first term is less than or equal to the next and so on.

And if that is true, return `True`, and if not, return `False`.

Thank you very much.

Comment: It is not a good idea to reassign the standard list type.

Comment: Why does the title of your question say decreasing *or* ascending yet you only check for less that or equal to the next?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Anything not working when you use a usual loop?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to test whether the list is sorted.

```
def is_sorted(seq):
    return seq == sorted(seq)
```

Comment: no, what I want to know is whether the list is sorted in order from lowest to highest.

Comment: What do you mean by shortest to longest? What is the intended comparison operator if not <?

Comment: The would not work if the list was in descending order.

Comment: @Jeremy I'm highly skeptical. The standard sorted function is implemented in C, which a Python loop will struggle to beat for performance. If you have evidence to prove your claim, please post it. (Edit) The point is well made that for a huge list, the sorted solution is certainly worse than one that short circuits appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this (for a list `x` - best not to name a list `list`):

```
all(x[i] <= x[i+1] for i in range(len(x)-1))
```

which has the benefit that it stops comparing once a result makes the answer `False`.

Examples:

```
>>> x = [0, 1, 8, 10, 14, 16]
>>> all(x[i] <= x[i+1] for i in range(len(x)-1))
True

>>> x = [0, 1, 8, 10, 17, 16]
>>> all(x[i] <= x[i+1] for i in range(len(x)-1))
False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use functions like this:

```py
listA = [0, 1, 8 , 10, 14, 16]
listB = [16, 14, 10 , 8, 1, 0]


def isAscending(input):
    j = float('-inf')
    for i in input:
        if i<j : 
            return False
        j = i
    return True
        
def isDescending(input):
    j = float('inf')
    for i in input:
        if i>j : 
            return False
        j = i
    return True
        
print(isAscending(listA))  # -> True
print(isDescending(listA)) # -> False

print(isAscending(listB))  # -> False
print(isDescending(listB)) # -> True
```

Checking if the list is **sorted** will also work (*as in @PasserBy 's answer*).
You can also use a function like this (this one also handles lists in descending order):

```py
def isValid(input):
    return input == sorted(input) or input == sorted(input , reverse = True)
    
print(isValid(listA)) # -> True
print(isValid(listB)) # -> True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if two consecutive terms are in increasing order you can pair them with `zip` and then compare.

```
new_list = [0, 1, 8 , 3, 10, 14, 16, 12]

is_pairwise_ascending_order = [i <= j for i, j in zip(new_list[:-1], new_list[1:])]

print(is_pairwise_ascending_order)
```

Output

```
[True, True, False, True, True, True, False]
```

Finally, to check if the list is in ascending sequence you could use, for example, `all` built-in function (as done in another solution) or `False not in is_pairwise_ascending_order`